# How do I set this text box on top of the TradingView screen

Tags: tradingview-api

Basically the title of the thread. I been trying to get that little text box but I don't honestly have clue of how to. Appreciate!

[HERE YOU CAN SEE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMn9n.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this indicator in tradingview:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).